# Design in css rounded border in three sides and one with disconnected corner

Tags: css, css-transitions

Can you please me create design in css which is available in the below link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmiSr.png

Comment: Unfortunately people will be reluctant to do your work for you. We are here to help you do the work yourself by helping you with specific issues. Put some effort into the task, show us how far you got and then put some effort into writing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .upperdiv {
        width: 200px;
        height: 80px;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }

    .upperdiv::before {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 2em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        content: '';
        background: white;
    }

    .TL::before {
        margin: -28px;
        padding: 2em;
    }

    .TR::before {
        margin: -28px;
        margin-left: 167px;
    }

    .lowerdiv {
        width: 200px;
        height: 80px;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border-top: 0px solid;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }

    .lowerdiv::before {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 2em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        content: '';
        background: white;
    }

    .BR::before {
        margin: -28px;
        margin-top: 45px;
        margin-left: 167px;
    }

    .BL::before {
        margin: -28px;
        margin-top: 45px;
        margin-left: -33px;
    }

    .container {
        margin: 3em;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="upperdiv TL"></div>
        <div class="lowerdiv"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="upperdiv TR"></div>
        <div class="lowerdiv"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="upperdiv"></div>
        <div class="lowerdiv BR"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="upperdiv"></div>
        <div class="lowerdiv BL"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.contentsTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.contentsBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 25px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hideCorner {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
}

.top-left {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.top-right {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.bottom-left {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.bottom-right {
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hideCorner top-left"></div>
  <div class="contentsTop">TOP LEFT</div>
  <div class="contentsBottom">TOP LEFT</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="hideCorner top-right"></div>
  <div class="contentsTop">TOP RIGHT</div>
  <div class="contentsBottom">TOP RIGHT</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="hideCorner bottom-left"></div>
  <div class="contentsTop">BOTTOM LEFT</div>
  <div class="contentsBottom">BOTTOM LEFT</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="hideCorner bottom-right"></div>
  <div class="contentsTop">BOTTOM RIGHT</div>
  <div class="contentsBottom">BOTTOM RIGHT</div>
</div>
```